# sql show total count before doing group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to see the total count before doing a group by.

I have this table.

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| match_id | date       | tournament | playerA | playerB | scoreA | scoreB | offline |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
|        1 | 2012-12-04 |        799 |       4 |      55 |      1 |      3 |       0 |
|        2 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |       2 |      41 |      2 |      0 |       0 |
|        3 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      21 |      41 |      0 |      2 |       0 |
|        4 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |       3 |       2 |      2 |      1 |       0 |
|        5 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      41 |       2 |      1 |      2 |       0 |
|        6 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      21 |       3 |      1 |      2 |       0 |
|        7 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      1 |       1 |
|        8 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      3 |       1 |
|        9 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       8 |      19 |      3 |      2 |       1 |
|       10 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |      19 |      12 |      2 |      1 |       1 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Sqlfiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d661/1

This is what I tried.

```
SELECT *, count(*), count(scoreA > scoreB) as SA, count(scoreA < scoreB) as SB
from matches
    Group By playerA, scoreA > scoreB, scoreA < scoreB;
```

Then I thought having a subquery might work.

```
SELECT count(playerA)
from matches
Group By playerA
(
SELECT *, count(*), count(scoreA > scoreB) as SA, count(scoreA < scoreB) as SB
from matches
    Group By playerA, scoreA > scoreB, scoreA < scoreB);
```

Neither method worked for me.

Expected results

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+----------+-----+-----+
| match_id | date       | tournament | playerA | playerB | scoreA | scoreB | offline | count(*) | SA  | SB  |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+----------+-----+-----+
|      823 | 2012-11-04 |       3480 |       1 |       7 |      2 |      2 |       1 |        195 |   1 |   1 |
|        8 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      3 |       1 |       195 |  131 |  61 |
|        7 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      1 |       1 |      195 | 133 | 61 |
```

If you look at the last couple of columns on the expected results table it is 1, 61, and 133. I don't really understand why SA and SB are always the same though.

`1 + 61 + 133 = 195`

Comment: What is the logic for getting the expected results? Are you generating new match id and tournament column values? Please elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @clinomaniac If you look at the last couple of columns on the expected results table it is 1, 61, and 133. I don't really understand why SA and SB are always the same though. I am working with huge tables thats why the numbers are so high. 

`1 + 61 + 133 = 195`

Comment: *I don't really understand why SA and SB are always the same though.* Eh? But it's *your* expected result !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry sorry those were the results I was getting. It is now changed to the results I am expecting.

Comment: Even after reading this question several times over, I still don't understand what count is being attempted.  Clearly describe what you are trying to Count...

Comment: @Zorkolot I'm sorry I'm not good at explaining myself. Take a look at this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d661/1 In the first query `player 1` has a count of `2` in the second query `player 1` has two separate counts of `1`. I want a way to retrieve that count of  `2` while doing that second query.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected results look little subpar, but you may need to try something like this,

```
select m.playerA, count(SA.*), count(SB.*)
from matches m
inner join 
    (select *
    from matches 
    where scoreA > scoreB) SA
on m.match_id = SA.match_id
inner join
    (select *
    from matches 
    where scoreA < scoreB) SB
on m.match_id = SB.match_id
group by m.playerA
```

Comment: can you explain the `SA.*` part. That is the part I don't get.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the sqlfiddle you posted, I think this is what you're attempting:

```
SELECT player
      ,team
      ,start_date
      ,end_date
      ,(SELECT count(player) 
          FROM members M2
         WHERE M2.player = M.player
         group by player) AS count
  FROM members M
  group by player, team
```

Here's an edited sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09d661/4/1

Comment: thank you for having the patience to figure out what I needed.